# modal height auto setting

Tags: html, css, image, styled-components

The modal window that appears when I click one of the main page elements, and the vertical length (height) of the main page itself are auto setting. However, if I put an image with the height set to auto in the modal window, the problem arises. Even if I change the overflow setting, the page can not scrolled so that I can not see the entire image. It seems to be fixed to the auto value on the main page. How can I fix this problem?

layout.jsx

```
    function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.layout}>
      <Header />
      <main className={styles.main}> {props.children} </main>
      {/*<Footer />       */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

layout.module.css

```
.layout{
 /* padding-top: 80px;*/
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
}

.main{
  min-height: 1024px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'NotoSansKR-400';
}
```

RefModal.jsx

```
export default function RefModal({id2, modalVisibleId2, setModalVisibleId2, idea}) {
//Omit some code

  const media = idea.attached_file
  return (
    <MS.ModalWrapper className={modalVisibleId2 == id2 ? classes.show : classes.dis}>
    <MS.MobalBox>
      //Omit some code
        <MS.MobalContents>
          {media && media.map((i)=> 
            i.one.split('.',-1)[i.one.split('.',-1).length-1]==="jpg" ? 
            <MS.ContentImg src={require('../../images/'+i.one)} />
             : "")}
          {media && media.map((i)=> 
            i.two.split('.',-1)[i.two.split('.',-1).length-1]==="jpg" ? 
            <MS.ContentImg src={require('../../images/'+i.two)} />
             : "")}
          <p>{id2}</p>
        </MS.MobalContents>
  
        <MS.TraceBoxWrapper>
          <MS.TraceBox onClick={() => handleLike(idea.thumbs)}>
            <FavoriteOutlinedIcon className={likeBoolean?classes.afterClick1:classes.beforeClick} />
            {like}
          </MS.TraceBox>
          <div style={{width:"26px"}}></div>
          <MS.TraceBox onClick={() => handleSubscribe(idea.scrap)}>
            <StarIcon className={subscribeBoolean?classes.afterClick2:classes.beforeClick} />
            {subscribe}
          </MS.TraceBox>
        </MS.TraceBoxWrapper>

        <RefModalComment />
    </MS.MobalBox>
    
  </MS.ModalWrapper>
  )
}
```

ModalStyle.jsx

```
export const MS = {
//omit some code
  HeaderUserInfo:styled.div`
    top:35%;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
  `,
  HeaderUserName:styled.span`
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  `,
  HeaderDetail2:styled.div`
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    left:25%;
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: space-between;
  `,
  DetailFeedbackButton:styled.button`
    left: 10%;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    top: 40%;
    height: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  `,
  ModalContents:styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: pink;
  `,
  TraceBoxWrapper:styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  `,
  TraceBox:styled.div`
    border: 2px solid #FADA5E;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 123px;
    height: 53px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 50px;
  `,
  ContentImg:styled.img`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  `
}
```

I hope the auto value on the main page is effected by the height of the modal window.

Comment: Please create a complete snippet with your code.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.